# Leaflet show all popups of all the makers and keep in the map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I refer to [Quick Start Guide - Leaflet - a JavaScript library for interactive maps](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) to implement show marker on the map.

I want to show all popups of all the markers,and if I click on the map,it still keep the popups.

The bottleNeck is

1.How to change the code to show multiple popups of the markers

2.How to keep the popups if I click on the map

Because I google this,I can't find the solution.
Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a modified version of Leaflet's quickstart tutorial.
It adds three markers with their own, individual popups and keeps the open:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(mymap);

var markers = [
    {pos: [51.51, -0.10], popup: "This is the popup for marker #1"},
    {pos: [51.50, -0.09], popup: "This is the popup for marker #2"},
    {pos: [51.49, -0.08], popup: "This is the popup for marker #3"}];
markers.forEach(function (obj) {
    var m = L.marker(obj.pos).addTo(mymap),
        p = new L.Popup({ autoClose: false, closeOnClick: false })
                .setContent(obj.popup)
                .setLatLng(obj.pos);
    m.bindPopup(p);
});
```

The key points are:

- each marker needs its own popup layer
- the popup layers need to be configured with `autoClose: false` (=> the popup is not closed when another popup is opened) and `closeOnClick: false` (=> the popup is not closed when the map is clicked).

Comment: needed to change the bindPopup() line to `m.bindPopup(p).openPopup();` to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    
    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(mymap);
    
    var markers = [
        {pos: [51.51, -0.10], popup: "This is the popup for marker #1"},
        {pos: [51.50, -0.09], popup: "This is the popup for marker #2"},
        {pos: [51.49, -0.08], popup: "This is the popup for marker #3"}];
    markers.forEach(function (obj) {
        var m = L.marker(obj.pos).addTo(mymap),
            p = new L.Popup({ autoClose: false, closeOnClick: false })
                    .setContent(obj.popup)
                    .setLatLng(obj.pos);
        m.bindPopup(p);
    });

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
                    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
                    var allLocation = document.querySelectorAll('.leaflet-marker-pane img')
                    allLocation.forEach((location)=>{
                        location.click()

                    })
                });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
            var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [11.8166, 122.0942],
        zoom:8,
    
      });
    
        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);
    
        var LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
            options: {
            //  shadowUrl: 'images/marker-shadow.png',
                iconSize:     [25, 41],
                shadowSize:   [41, 41],
                iconAnchor:   [22, 41],
            //  shadowAnchor: [22, 40],//map shadow position change 
                popupAnchor:  [-10, -44] // map popup position 
            }
        });
    
        var pinIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: 'https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png'});
        
    
        
    
     // lat long and popup description
     var locations = [
      ["Hello World!", 11.8166, 122.0942],
      ["Hello world! 2", 11.9804, 121.9189],
      ["Hello world!", 10.7202, 122.5621],
      ["Hello world!", 11.3889, 122.6277],
      ["Hello world!", 10.5929, 122.6325]
    ];
      var latLngArr = []; // make empty array for long lat
    
    // autoClose:false 
    // .openPopup() added for auto content opened
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new L.marker([locations[i][1], locations[i][2]],pinIcon)
        .bindPopup(locations[i][0],{autoClose:false})
        .addTo(map)
        .openPopup();
        latLngArr.push([locations[i][1], locations[i][2]]);
    }
    // map center 
     map.fitBounds(latLngArr);
```

Comment: Example url https://codepen.io/ikefti/pen/ExQrRJZ

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).